# CSS Outline font issue

Tags: css, typography

This might have been answered, but i couldn't find how to fix it. I'm having trouble with css outline on some text. It appears to outline multiple lines in the same letter. Here is what it looks like :
[image: Screenshot of the issue]

And here is the code i'm using:

```
.big-outline-text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: $black30;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
```

Is this an issue with my code? Or with the font file? How can i fix it?

Thanks a lot for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have provided it is something else that is conflicting. I've put your css in jsfiddle and it appears with only one outline.

https://jsfiddle.net/rocv3tf9/1/

HTML

```
<div class="big-outline-text">
What
</div>
```

CSS

```
.big-outline-text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: $black30;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, there was an issue when i converted the font to webfont using Glyphs. I've reworked it, exported it again and it works fine!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out :-)